# OWIN existing implementation issues & whether there is a good authentication architecture?

Tags: c#, security, oauth-2.0, owin

I 'm new to this forum, recently I 'm going through an existing C# MVC api code where OWIN is implemented, so, the issue is access token gets expired(after 20 min) even though the client is actively doing something on server side or from UI side, which I feel is incorrect, the token should expire only when the client is inactive post 20 min, so is there a way to stop token expiration if the client is active?

I have seen the concept of refresh token however that seems to be little tricky, I need to somehow keep track of user session on client side when the client logins, so the session is about to complete 20 min, I need to fire a post request with the refresh token, this is includes a lot of code on client side, well and if I'm doing the same thing via postman or windows service then I can't logically keep track of time, so is there a way OWIN will take care of all this? so that I don't need to keep track of any sessions, OWIN will automatically create a new access token post expiration using refresh token. Please do let me know if this is good architecture and is there any security breach if refresh token is used ? And Any new functionalities added ?

Could you please also let me know if there is any good architecture better than OWIN ??

Here is my existing code just for access token.

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureOAuth(app);
        //Rest of code is here;
        }

        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
                Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider()
            };

            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        }
```

There are other pieces of code as well however that is something standard which can be found anywhere.

Comment: Tokens are fixed and signed. So if you change something in it (`exp` for example) - you need to sign it again and this will be **another** token. However - you are free to implement any authentication system you like.

Comment: Also, stackoverflow is not a "forum", it's "Q&A network"

Comment: Any help on this, need an urgent attention from the experts